# VUEJS Check if user liked post

Tags: vue.js

I want to check if user is already like the post. I get an array with users who liked the post but I don't know how to hide button if logged in `username` exists in the `likes` array. Heres the code part:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for this, just replace the `Zlotte` with current use username:

```html
<button
  v-if="!b.likes.find(u => u.username === 'Zlotte')"
  class="likeButton"
  @click="like(b._id)"
>
  LIKE
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this is by creating a computed with this code in it:

```
return b.likes.filter(({ username }) => username === <here the variable for the current username>).length;
```

More readable variant:

```
return b.likes.filter((like) => {
    return like.username === <here the variable for the current username>;
}).length;
```

I'm not sure of the structure of `b`, so I'm not sure if you have the current users' name available in there.

If you have added the computed, you can use it in the template to `v-if` or `v-show` the button:

```
<button class="likeButton" @click="like(b._id)" v-if="<name of the computed here>">LIKE</button>
```

Comment: `b` is from `<li v-for="b in budskaps" :key="b._id">` So I cannot use it like this...

Comment: Could you maybe update your post with a bit more context? So I can help you out :)

Comment: The accepted answer use 'find' function which stops processing when the first element searched is found. Do not use 'filter' for performance reasons.